# How to use the trained algorithm for tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have installed the tensorflow and follow the tutorial here

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/tutorials/mnist/tf/index.html#tensorflow-mechanics-101

and build it successfully, I can get the evaluation result for the same size dataset, like 1000X784 for training set, and 1000X784 for testing set.

but what if i want to test one data, 1X784, and find out what's the output, using the algorithm trained above.

I am now to tensorflow, and new to Machine Learning, I hope that I have described my self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me which part you're having trouble with, but I think what you're asking is how to use batch size 1000 for training, but only predict on a single input. I assume you already know how to predict on batches of size 1000.

If the first dimension of your model's input placeholder, which is usually the batch size, is set to be None, the size is inferred when you provide an input. So, if you change the 1000 to be None, you should then be able to pass an input of size 1 by 784 to make predictions.

Comment: It really works! thanks.
And I also found another way, create a new tensor, feed a 1X784 input, then run that tensor.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that you found to feed a 1*784 is a great solution to just get a quick feed back , however in bigger networks which they need a lot of time (around hours) for training your solution is not feasible.

Tensorflow they have a new feature it's name is Tensorflow serving which you give it a train model then you  interact with your model as a client.

Here is their website for more information : https://github.com/tensorflow/serving